# Forecasting of a dynamac's package object

Tags: r, forecast

I have an ARDL model with co-integration so I used the "dynamac" package in R. I need to forecast for some horizons (different at each time). When I apply the forecast function from the package "forecast" an error occurs due to the fact that the "new data" were not imported.

```
ARDL_Model <- dynamac::dynardl(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 , data = My_Data,
                                   diffs = c("X1","X2", "X3","X4"),
                                   lagdiffs = list("X1" = c(1:5),"X2" = 1, "X3" = c(1:2), "X4" = c(1:2)), ec = TRUE, simulate = TRUE,shockvar = "X2", graph= TRUE)

forecast(All_ARDL_Model$model,h=1)#Horizon 1
```

> R output - (forecast command):
>   Error in as.data.frame(newdata) : 
>     argument "newdata" is missing, with no default

Comment: The function `forecast` is only for objects produced by the `forecast` package. Try `predict` instead. Check `?dynardl`. It should explain how the function works.

Comment: You are right and thanks! Although I still have a problem because a typical ARDL model should not forecast using it's own data (and that's what "predict" function does)... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but your code already includes the relevant forecasting.

```
ARDL_Model <- dynamac::dynardl(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 , data = My_Data,
diffs = c("X1","X2", "X3","X4"),
lagdiffs = list("X1" = c(1:5), "X2" = 1, "X3" = c(1:2), "X4" = c(1:2)), 
ec = TRUE, simulate = TRUE, shockvar = "X2", graph= TRUE)
```

Will create a set of simulated results in `ARDL_Model$simulate`. `ARDL_Model$simulate$central` is the response of the dependent variable. At `shocktime` (since it isn't specified here will default to t = 10), `X2` will be shocked by a standard deviation of its value (since `shockval` isn't specified). The other variables will be held at their means. So you will be able to forecast the response of the dependent variable, but will need to run a separate simulation (i.e. for each `shockvar` and `shockval` you'd like to forecast a response).

The vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynamac/vignettes/dynamac-vignette.html might also be useful.